# Spring Cloud : Route request to particular microservice instance

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-ribbon

I am using ZUUL with Eureka.

Lets say, I have two instances of microservice, say test.
Their configuration is as follows

```
spring:
  application:
    name: test
server:
  port: 7878
eureka:
  instance:
    metadata-map:
      version: 1
```

and

```
spring:
  application:
    name: test
server:
  port: 7879    
eureka:
  instance:
    metadata-map:
      version: 2
```

If I send `version: 1` in http header then request should go to first instance of microservice and if `version: 2` then it should go to second instance microservice.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: I think you would need to add a Filter in your Zuul server that checks the headers.

Comment: I am trying that, but I am not able to figure out how to get service id(ie application name) in ZUUL filter for particular request.

Comment: You have the request object in the filter so you can get the requested URIs and paths which should tell you what application is being requested

Comment: But how to get service  ID from request path ? Once I get request ID, I can get all available instances using discovery client.

Comment: The clients are asking ZUUL for some "path" that they want. Zuul is taking that path and routing.  I assume that you have zuul.routes.* defined somewhere currently.